# function something with tag and value that takes two strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question that I have been trying to figure out for hours, but the problem is, I don't know what I am being asked to do so I don't even know where to start with the question. I am very uneducated in coding and have no clue at all what my first step would be and how I would go about the problem. The question gives me HTML code and asks me the following:

> Write a function replace(tag, value) that takes two strings as argument. The first is a tag (e.g, "item" (without quotes) and the second is a replacement value (e.g., "flux capacitor" (without quotes). This function should replace the innerHTML of the element with the given tag with the specified value. If the tag does not exist your function should display an alert to indicate that the tag was not found. Test your code by defining the format() function which is tied to the Format button by replacing 'salutation' with 'Mr. Smith', 'invoice' with 123, 'item' with 'flux capacitor' and 'threaten' with 'Please do not make me angry.'
>
> Write a function clearit() that removes all of the content from the
> page contained within the tag with id='buttons'. Do not assume that
> the 'buttons' tag only contains two items.

Heres the html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="q1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Dear <span id="salutation">Name</span>;
        <p>
            It has come to our attention that your invoice <span id="invoice">ID</span>
            has yet to be paid. It has now been <span id="time">some time</span> since
            you received <span id="item">the material</span> from Evil Incorporated. Please
            remit payment immediately. <span id="threaten"></span>
        </p>
        Yours sincerely,<br>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        J. Smith, Accounting
        <div id="buttons">
            <center>
                <button onclick="format()">Format</button>
                <button onclick="clearit()">Clear</button>
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're being asked to write a function that replaces one value with another. See how the Format button invokes a format() function when you click it? You need to write a function that replaces the text inside the <span id="salutation"></span> ('Name') with 'Mr. Smith'. Same goes for some other values mentioned in the question. The output of the text should include all logical values, so instead of 'Dear Name', it would say 'Dear Mr. Smith'. And so on for the other values

Comment: @Meldon so it would be an if or else statements?

Comment: To check whether the tag exists, yeah. Have a look at Hunan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

To help you get started, I've annotated the spec with a function that you can fill in, step by step. Note that we can't use `getElementsByTagName`, because replace doesn't take an argument specifying which of those possibly many tags it should operate with. Therefore, I have made the assumption that the spec really meant to speak of IDs when it spoke of tags.

```
// `id` and `value` are Strings
function replace(id, value) {

  // Get the element with id `id`
  var elmt = /* (Task 1) Look into `document.getElementById` */

  // If the element is not found, display an alert.
  if (/* (Task 2) Check if `elmt` is falsy */) {

    // (Task 3) Display the alert here.

  // Otherwise, replace the contents.
  } else {

    // (Task 4) set `elmt`'s innerHTML to `value`.

  }

}
```

And here are the test helpers.

```
function format() {
  replace('salutation', 'Mr. Smith');   
  replace('invoice', '123'); 
  replace('item', 'flux capacitor');
  replace('threaten', 'Please do not make me angry.');
}

function clearit() {
  replace('buttons', '');
}
```

Comment: @MikeWilsom np. Good luck.